# working of SQL server transactions using ASP .net

Tags: .net, sql, select, transactions

I have an ASP .net application that calls a webservice. The webservice calls the data access classes to update the database.

I have a code snippet(actually a pseudocode) in my webservice similar to the following:

```
Public Function SubmitCheque(//params are passed here)
     //Call sql stored procedure(SP1) to generate a reference Number

     //Begin loop. loop count would be number of records that are in a collection
       //Insert records to database using another stored procedure(SP2) using the
       //reference number generated in the previous step
     //End Loop
End Function
```

SP1 performs a select query on a table, get the last row's column value and then increments its sequence by 1. Say if the last row's value is ABC02282012**56**, then my new reference number would be ABC02282012**57**

SP2 performs a single insert statement, and the row that it inserts will have the reference number that was generated.

Here is the problem that is expected to occur and I am not sure about the right way  to do it.

In my code SP1 and SP2 executes sequentially, and in a millisecond of time interval between SP1 and SP2 there is a possiblity that another instance of the application would have executed SP1 and can get the same transaction number. So there is a possiblity that multiple  users accessing the application simultaneously might end up in getting a same transaction number which is a big problem.

I wanted to know if this is something that SQL server will take care or do I need to re-write the stored procedure or code in a different way to implement a transaction.

Please help and let me know your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better implementing all the logic inside a single stored procedure, with the statements wrapped inside a suitable transaction.

Failing that use a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) to enlist your separate actions in a transaction. e.g.:

```
try
{
    // Create the TransactionScope to execute the commands, guaranteeing
    // that both commands can commit or roll back as a single unit of work.
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
        {
            // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
            // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
            connection1.Open();


           // Call sql stored procedure(SP1) to generate a reference Number                 

           SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
           returnValue = command1.ExecuteScalar();


          //Begin loop. loop count would be number of records that are in a collection 
              //Insert records to database using another stored procedure(SP2) using the 
              //reference number generated in the previous step 
          //End Loop 

        }
        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I understand but there is a .net collection, that contains several payment instructions(say for instance 4 payments and the count can even be 10). If I pass these as parameters to my Stored procedure then my stored procedures input parameters might look way too lengthy.

Comment: I am looking in to the TransactionScope. If I wrap the SP calls in a TransactionScope, will it be considered as a single transaction?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code snippet. One difference is that the function that I have does not have any SQL connections opened. Its only the other class library functions(which are called from my service) that have the SQL connections opened. \n Will this case still be considered as a transaction when using transaction scope.

Comment: only if the connections are opened after the transaction scope is created, and if they do not explicitly specify that they run outside of a transaction (unlikely).